# At what value of y does the population grow the fastest? Why?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wasn't sure how to solve $\frac{dy}{dt} = y(4-y^2)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a population model, we consider the model only for $y\geq 0$.

$\frac{dy}{dt}$ ist the growth rate. So, you need to find the maximum of $f(y)=y(4-y^2)$ for $y\geq 0$.

Using the classical derivative test, you find that the growth rate is maximal for $\boxed{y = \frac 2{\sqrt 3}}$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Use partial fractions $$\frac{dy}{dt} = y(4-y^2)$$
$$\frac{dy}{y(4-y^2)}=dt$$
$$\frac14\left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{y^2-4}\right)dy=dt$$

Comment: Although correct, solving the ODE is not needed for this problem.

Comment: OP has asked how to solve O.D.E. so I just gave a hint